# strange behavior with EditText inside <include> tag

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view which include another one with the "include" component (see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html)
There is some EditText inside the included view.

There is some problems with these EditText :

- I have to tap them 2 times in order to have the keyboard to appear
- if I long press one of the EditText the app freeze and crash (only on my phone - Samsung galaxy S, not on the emulator)

It does not happen if the Edittext are NOT in a `<include>` tag ...
Do you have any ideas on this problem ??

regards,
Christophe

Comment: Are you by any chance including the same layout twice in the same XML file (have 2 EditTexts with the same id)?

Comment: I just check, the IDs are unique and the layout is only included once.

Comment: post your xml for both the *including* and *included* layouts

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have the same problem about long click EditText or TextView crash on Samsung device with Android 4.0 up.

The crash log in here

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
at android.widget.TextView$SelectionActionModeCallback.onCreateActionMode(TextView.java:10647)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2382)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2322)
at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:3687)
at android.widget.TextView.startSelectionActionMode(TextView.java:10451)
at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9570)
at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:14241)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

It's because when you long click on text, samsung system will select text to highlight
and use onCreateActionMode() to show cut, copy, paste etc button.

If you are in Android 4.0 up, 
it will show on ActionBar and use the ActionBar theme style in your app's style.xml.
And I found my

```
"@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton"
```

set minWidth to zero,
cause samsung system calculate action button position resulted

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
```

Finally set minWidth to not zero, the problem solved.

Comment: same problem here,how exactly can you set minWidth to zero?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to comment on the answer given below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11966733/1777346) but don't have enough reputation points yet!

We also ran into the same "java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero" exception on Samsung devices (didn't test other devices.. all Samsung). It would occur when long-pressing existing text in an EditText field.

The solution below worked.. we had the following style defined. Changing minWidth to "1" fixed this.

```
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
```